# What exactly is a Heroku compute on a Dyno?

Tags: heroku, cloud

Heroku describes their dynos [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types) and it lists the amount of memory each one has and also the amount of Compute resources. Nowhere do I see the definition of a "Compute".

When I run this command on the performance-l dynos it tells me it has **8** cores.

```
grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

I don't see how this relates to the **46x Compute** that's on the chart. It seems like an arbitrary number to me and I don't understand exactly what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku's compute units are just Amazon's compute units (because Heroku runs on top of AWS).

One [compute unit](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it) on AWS is defined as the computer power of a 1.0-1.2Ghz of a 2007 server CPU.

Keep in mind though: these units are typically pretty variable depending on how many other active dynos are on the same underlying EC2 host.